# PySpark testing: construct test data consisting array of structs

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I'd like to generate some test data for my unit tests in PySpark. One of the fields in input Row is an array of structs: `basket: array<struct<price:bigint,product_id:string>>`. Whats the best way to achieve it?

Comment: sumek can you provide some feedback regarding the solution below? Could you try to run it?

Comment: Hi abiratsis, thanks for the solution, but I no longer work on that piece of system ...

Comment: Hi sumek, sure no problem at all. Thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way using python and two helper functions responsible for generating the random data:

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from random import randrange, uniform

array_size = 2

def create_row(array_size):
  return ([{"price" : uniform(1.0, 100.0), "product_id" : randrange(10) + 1} for _ in range(array_size)],)

def generate_data(data_size):
  return [create_row(array_size) for _ in range(data_size)] 

# create 5 rows
rows = generate_data(5)

# string schema
schema = "basket: array<struct<price:double,product_id:string>>"

# static typing schema
# schema = StructType([
#             StructField('basket',
#                 ArrayType(
#                     StructType(
#                           [
#                               StructField('price', DoubleType()),
#                               StructField('product_id', StringType()),
#                           ]
#                     )
#                 )
#             )])

df = spark.createDataFrame(rows, schema)

df.show(10, False)

# +--------------------------------------------------+
# |basket                                            |
# +--------------------------------------------------+
# |[[61.40674765573896, 9], [5.994467505720648, 7]]  |
# |[[1.1388272509974906, 10], [47.32070824053193, 3]]|
# |[[42.423106687845795, 2], [70.99107361888588, 4]] |
# |[[50.019594333009806, 8], [63.51239439900147, 4]] |
# |[[68.15711374321089, 9], [70.06617125228864, 10]] |
# +--------------------------------------------------+
```

- **create_row**: will generate a new row (represented as a tuple here) with *array_size* items. `price` will have value in the range 1.0 - 100.0 and `product_id` in the range 1 - 10, please feel free to modify the boundaries accordingly. Also, we handle each item of the array (product_id-price pairs) with a python dictionary.
- **generate_data**: calls `create_row` data_size times and returns the random generated rows into a list.